# Error thin client and Restlet Server + objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, serialization, restlet

I'm trying to make communicate my (functionnal) Reslet server + Objectify framework, with a simple thin client.
I get a 500 Internal error, because it seems i'm sending a Null object (parse/serialization mistake?), but I don't know how to fix it, and I don't know that much about serialization. It would be awesome if you could help me ! :)

Here is my client :
its interface:

```
    public interface AdminControllerInterface {

         @Put
         void create(Epreuve ep);

         @Get
         Epreuve getAllEpreuve();
    }
```

its Controller :

```
public class AdminController {
   public final ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(
           EngineConfiguration.gae_path + "/rest/admin");

   public AdminController() {
       EngineConfiguration.getInstance();
   }

   public void create(Epreuve epreuve) throws Exception {
       final AdminControllerInterface uci = cr.wrap(AdminControllerInterface.class);

       try {
           uci.create(epreuve);
               System.out.println( "Creation success !");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println( "Creation failed !");
               throw e;
       }
   }

    public Epreuve getAllEpreuve(final long ordre) {
        //lets focus on the create method first
    }
}
```

Server side : the interface's the same and the controller :

```
public class AdminController extends ServerResource implements AdminControllerInterface{

    @Override
    public void create(Epreuve ep) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Epreuve epreuve = new Epreuve();
            epreuve.setQuestion(ep.getQuestion());
            epreuve.setFirstAnswer(ep.getFirstAnswer());
            epreuve.setSecondAnswer(ep.getSecondAnswer());
            epreuve.setTrueAnswer(ep.getTrueAnswer());
            epreuve.setTimeToAnswer(ep.getTimeToAnswer());
            epreuve.setLatitude(ep.getLatitude());
            epreuve.setLongitude(ep.getLongitude());
            epreuve.setVille(ep.getVille());
            epreuve.setOrdre(ep.getOrdre());

            ofy().save().entity(epreuve).now();

    }

    @Override
    public Epreuve getAllEpreuv() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Server returns 500 - internal error while trying to do ep.getQuestion() => it's produce nullPointerException. Any idea about what I did wrong ? :)

Comment: And where does the object come from in create(Epreuve epreuve)? Why don't you test if it's null before you call your server?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Just before uci.create(epreuve), I did a System.out.println(epreuve.toString()) and saw that all the fields were correctly set. :/

Comment: @L3I_Akuni You may want to add a Null check before sending to server the request object, also in the create method you have there, you can add a Precondition.checkNotNull to see if the data you got is not null.